# jQuery Mousewheel event coupled with element animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

**Scenario:**

I need to create a curve animation (arc shaped), which triggers by mousewheel.

So, I have comeup with some code.

**[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/Tfwqu/)**

```
var arc = {
    center: [-200, ($(window).height() - 24) / 2],
    // height + padding
    radius: 450,
    start: 0,
    end: 90,
    dir: 1
}

$('.point').each(function () {
    $(this).data('lastEnd', arc.end).animate({
        path: new $.path.arc(arc)
    }, 0);

    arc.start -= 10;
    arc.end -= 8;
});

$('body').mousewheel(function (e, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var delta = delta * -1;
    $('.point').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var startPoint = $this.data('lastEnd');
        var arc = {
            center: [-200, ($(window).height() - 24) / 2],
            radius: 450,
            start: startPoint,
            end: (delta * 8) + startPoint,
            dir: delta > 0 ? 1 : -1
        }
        $this.data('lastEnd', arc.end);

        $(this).animate({
            path: new $.path.arc(arc)
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

I am using [jQuery path](https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path) for curve animation, and

[jQuery mousewheel](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/) to trigger event on mousewheel.

**Problem:**

Mousewheel just gives me direction of mousewheel, but not the velocity. So, if user scrolls faster, instead of giving increased `delta`, it fires mousewheel event multiple times.
It would have been worked in simple situations, but I am animating the points. So, multiple mousewheel events trigger, before the animation finishes. ( You can see it by scrolling faster )

**What I tried:**

1. I restricted multiple mousewheel events by putting a flag `isScrolling`, and restrict scrolling, if `isScrolling` is true. But, that does not give me smooth animation. Until the animation finishes, mousescroll does nothing.
2. I used `setTimeout` to hold scrolling for few milliseconds and summing all the deltas fired in that period, but it's also not smooth.
3. I tried using `stop()`. But `stop()` stops the animation in midway and I want atleast one point at the position of *marker* (not above / below it)

**What I want:**

Smooth animation with mousewheel ( just like the normal scroll on a page). Faster mousewheel scrolling should scroll more than the normal (one scroll at a time) scrolling.

**UPDATE 1:**

My progress since yesterday can be seen **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/Tfwqu/3/)**

Now, I am using `setTimeout` to sum up `deltas` before starting animation and then using a relative duration to animate faster in bigger deltas and slower in smaller ones.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `css`-method from `$.path.arc` and pass its returned `css`-object to `$.fn.animate`. To get the actual `css`-object now, use the mousewheel-`delta` to iterate over them:

```
var path = new $.path.arc(arc);
$this.stop().animate(path.css(delta-1), 500);
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Tfwqu/1/

To make this *smoother* you should use an easing-function:

```
$.easing.easeOutQuad = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return -c *(t/=d)*(t-2) + b;
};

...

var path = new $.path.arc(arc);
$this.stop().animate(path.css(delta-1), 500, 'easeOutQuad');
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Tfwqu/2/

Comment: thx for pointing me to `path.css`. But can you see that fast scrolling  breaks the angle ? It does not move in that curve anymore

Comment: Ok, do try when you time. I'll be trying meanwhile. I have found one more approach. I use setTimeout as mentioned in question, and then by dynamically changing the duration of `animate` based on delta, I am having a pretty smooth animation. Btw, +1 for your effort

Comment: @Jashwant Can you share the `setTimeout`-fiddle please? :)

Comment: strange but jsfiddle is not allowing me to update my code. Returns this error `Port: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. `. I'll try again later

Comment: Okay found problem in your approach. Angle breaks as plugin  not only changes `left` , `top` but also does `transform`. I removed the transform from plugin and it works slightly (fluctuates when I scroll faster). I need to know, why you passed `delta-1` in `css()` function. May be that's causing problem

Comment: I found out that the parameter `p` that is passed to `css()` is between 1 to 0 depending on animation progress. Thus, `0` should be passed, as we specify only the final values of properties (in `animate()` function)